# How to get specific text in a soup.find method on python?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm having multiple issues with trying to **scrape** a website when the CSS code are all the same. I'm still learning about the soup.find method and things I can do with it. The issue is there are several lines of CSS code on a webpage that has `<span class="list-quest"` and when I use  `soup.find(class_='list-quest')` for example I will only get the result from the top of the page that uses the same CSS code. Is there a way to get the exact specific line of code? Possibly using `Born [dd-mm-yyyy]` ? But sadly I do not know how to use a specific keyword such as that for Python to find it.

```
<span class="list-quest">Born [dd-mm-yyyy]:</span>
```

Comment: would [findAll](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method:%20findAll(name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs)) help? Keep everything the same, but replace `find` with `findAll` and it will output a list of all matches.

Answer (score 0):

By using a regex on the text attribute :

**Regex :**

```
Born \d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}:
```

**Python Code :**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

text = '<span class="list-quest">Born 01-01-2019:</span>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(text,features='html.parser')
tag = soup.find('span',attrs={'class':'list-quest'} , text=re.compile(r'Born \d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}'))
print(tag.text)
```

**Demo :** [Here](https://repl.it/repls/PlainInexperiencedProcedurallanguage)

Answer (score 0):

You might, with bs4 4.7.1 + be able to use contains

```
item = soup.select_one('span.list-quest:contains("Born ")')
if item is not None: print(item.text)
```

Comment: Ah yes, this is perfectly what I was looking for. However, so there is text right after the closing of </span>. And it outputs the persons age. How can I grab that text? Not sure if it helps, but it's all inside a <li></li> but like I said above, there are tons of results with the same type of code such as the <li>. If you need more info, let me know.

Comment: I can’t see that in the html provided. Is there more html to add ?